# Implement spring custom annotation acts like @Transactional

Tags: java, spring

I'd like to implement some common annotation acts like `@Transactional` annotation.

After digging spring core code and done some googling, I learned that if I put `@Transactional` annotation to a method, then the method get wrapped by a proxy. But still, I don't get how to implement anything like that on my own.

Is there any detailed guide for this?

Answer (score 1):

Annotations are Java EE features and not specific to Spring. Let's say you want to implement a custom annotation called @CourseCode which validates that a course code starts with (a default value) 'ABC'. You may also want to override the default value to be validated as, say, 'XYZ' also.

You need to define "@interface" for  CourseCode and implement ConstraintValidator for it.

Here is an example:

Typical Usage

```
    @CourseCode(value="XYZ", message="must start with XYZ") // value and message are optional
    private String courseCode;
```

@CourseCode implementation

```
package my.package.springdemo.mvc.validation;

import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

import javax.validation.Constraint;
import javax.validation.Payload;

@Constraint(validatedBy = CourseCodeConstraintValidator.class)
@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.FIELD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface CourseCode {
    // Define default course code
    public String value() default "ABC";

    // Define default error message
    public String message() default "must start with ABC";

    // Define default groups
    public Class<?>[] groups() default {};

    // Define default payloads
    public Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

And here is ConstraintValidator implementation:

```
package my.package.springdemo.mvc.validation;

import javax.validation.ConstraintValidator;
import javax.validation.ConstraintValidatorContext;

public class CourseCodeConstraintValidator implements ConstraintValidator<CourseCode, String> {

    private String coursePrefix;

    @Override
    public void initialize(CourseCode theCourseCode) {
        coursePrefix = theCourseCode.value();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(String theCode, ConstraintValidatorContext theConstraintValidatorContext) {
        boolean result;

        if (theCode != null) {
            result = theCode.startsWith(coursePrefix);
        }
        else {
            result = true;
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer and your time but I know annotations are java stuff. The point of my question is how to implement method proxy using annotation.

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding the ask. Would this help? https://www.baeldung.com/spring-aop-annotation

Comment: The previous one depends on Spring AOP. If Spring AOP independent annotation is needed then AspectJ is the way forward. Here is an example: https://www.baeldung.com/aspectj

Comment: I will take look at them. Thanks for your concern :)

Comment: And one more for Spring + AspectJ from Spring 4 documentation: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.3.15.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-using-aspectj Suprisingly I did not find the reference in Spring 5!